# Does db Cassandra write info about ttl expire in CDC logs?

Tags: cassandra, change-data-capture

We use CDC for our Cassandra DB. Our data in tables changes by upsert(update/insert) operations and TTLs expiring. Upsert operations are written to CDC logs, but TTLs expiring are not. I hoped, TTLs will look like delete operations in CDC Log.

Can anybody say, does db Cassandra write info about ttl expire in CDC logs?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No. You need to track TTL handling upserts...

Comment: Thank for your reply! Can some Cassandra mechanism track TTL handling upserts? Or  should our application do this?

Comment: right now, there is no such things built-in. I know that some teams are solving that in applications. Search for the DataStax Accelerate conference - in 2019th there were several talks about CDC